# How to connect Firebase Crashlytics to android app

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

I am trying to connect with firebase Crashlytics and integrated as per the document on the firebase Website. But I am not able to track the issue in firebase and firebase continuously show is following error

Add the Firebase Android SDK (17.1.1 or higher) or Unity Plugin (6.15.0 or higher), then build, run, and crash your app.

actually, I did all steps to connect my app to Firebase Crashlytics but doesn't report my crashes.
I don't know what mistake I have?

it's my build.gradle(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Services Gradle plugin

// Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.silverpath.dido"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'

    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
}
```

and its other build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I hope someone helps me.

Comment: For report log with exception to crashlytics you need catch exception and call this `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(yourException);` Did you do this?